# What's the the integral of $\tan(4x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How is $\displaystyle \int \tan(4x) dx = \cos^2 (4x)$? Shouldn't it be $\ln(\sec(4x))$? I don't understand... Please, help.

Thank you.

Comment: It isn't. The $\ln \sec (4x)$ is also not right, but that misses only a constant factor ($\frac14$) and the arbitrary integration constant.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\tan x\,dx=-\log\cos x +C=\log\sec x+C\implies$$

$$\int\tan 4x\,dx=\frac14\int (4dx)\tan 4x=\frac14\log\sec 4x+C$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a correct method for the function as stated above,

\begin{eqnarray}
\int \tan(4x)dx &=& \frac{1}{4}\ln (\sec(4x)) + C.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int{\tan(4x)dx}=\int\frac{\sin(4x)dx}{\cos(4x)}=|u=\cos(4x)\Rightarrow -4\sin(4x)dx=dt\Rightarrow \sin(4x)dx=-\frac{1}{4}dt|
$$
$$
=-\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{dt}{t}=-\frac{1}{4}\ln|t|=-\frac{1}{4}\ln|\cos(4x)|=\frac{1}{4}(-1)\ln|\cos(4x)|=\frac{1}{4}\ln|\cos(4x)|^{-1}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{4}\ln|\frac{1}{\cos(4x)}|=\frac{1}{4}\ln|\sec(4x)|+C
$$